# How to convert JSON string column row into a queryable table

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have exported to BigQuery from Firestore a whole collection to perform certain queries on it.

After the data was populated in my BigQuery console, now I can query the whole set like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM `myapp-1a602.firestore_orders.orders_raw_changelog` 
LIMIT 1000
```

Now, this statement throws my different columns, but the one I'm looking for is the data column, in my data column is each document JSON, but is in json format and I need to query all this values.

Now, this is the data from one row

```
{
    "cart": [{
        "qty": 1,
        "description": "Sprite 1 L",
        "productName": "Sprite 1 Liter",
        "price": 1.99,
        "productId": 9
    }],
    "storeName": "My awesome shop",
    "status": 5,
    "timestamp": {
        "_seconds": 1590713204,
        "_nanoseconds": 916000000
    }
}
```

This data is inside the **data** column, so if I do this

```
SELECT data 
FROM `myapp-1a602.firestore_orders.orders_raw_changelog` 
LIMIT 1000
```

I will get all the json values for each document, but I don't know how to query that values, lets say I want to know all orders with **status 5 and shopName My awesome shop** , now, I need to do something with this json to convert it into a table ? does I need to perform the query in the json itself ?

How can I query this json output ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You canwork with the json functiosn like the

> ```
> CrEATE Table products (id Integer,attribs_json JSON );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO products VALUES (1,'{
>     "cart": [{
>         "qty": 1,
>         "description": "Sprite 1 L",
>         "productName": "Sprite 1 Liter",
>         "price": 1.99,
>         "productId": 9
>     }],
>     "storeName": "My awesome shop",
>     "status": 5,
>     "timestamp": {
>         "_seconds": 1590713204,
>         "_nanoseconds": 916000000
>     }
> }');
> ```

> ```
> select * from products where attribs_json->"$.status" 
> = 5 AND attribs_json->"$.storeName" 
> = 'My awesome shop';
> ```
>
> ```
> id | attribs_json                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
> -: | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | {"cart": [{"qty": 1, "price": 1.99, "productId": 9, "description": "Sprite 1 L", "productName": "Sprite 1 Liter"}], "status": 5, "storeName": "My awesome shop", "timestamp": {"_seconds": 1590713204, "_nanoseconds": 916000000}}
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5465caf5ca192ecf3ac950a78eaed5a8)*

> ```
> select attribs_json->"$.storeName",attribs_json->"$.status",attribs_json->"$.cart[0].qty" from products where attribs_json->"$.status" 
> = 5 AND attribs_json->"$.storeName" 
> = 'My awesome shop';
> ```
>
> ```
> attribs_json->"$.storeName" | attribs_json->"$.status" | attribs_json->"$.cart[0].qty"
> :-------------------------- | :----------------------- | :----------------------------
> "My awesome shop"           | 5                        | 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ba42477d7b4f7524b9a563614c7a9e1)*

And there is [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)  for mysql 5.7 and above.

Finally that is in the end only text, so you could use also [REGEXP or RLIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html)

To transfer the jaso again to rows, you can use [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)

Comment: The think is that I dont want to analize this json only, there is 400 rows of this kind

Comment: you can take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html

Comment: o also added a query that gives you the data from that jsona as row and column

Answer (score 0):

> I need to do something with this json to convert it into a table ? does I need to perform the query in the json itself ?

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(data, cart_item), 
  JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.status') AS status, 
  JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.storeName') AS storeName,
  JSON_EXTRACT(cart_item, '$.qty') AS qty,
  JSON_EXTRACT(cart_item, '$.description') AS description,
  JSON_EXTRACT(cart_item, '$.productName') AS productName,
  JSON_EXTRACT(cart_item, '$.price') AS price,
  JSON_EXTRACT(cart_item, '$.productId') AS productId
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(data, '$.cart')) cart_item
```

If to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 order_id, '''
{
    "cart": [{
        "qty": 1,
        "description": "Sprite 1 L",
        "productName": "Sprite 1 Liter",
        "price": 1.99,
        "productId": 9
    },{
        "qty": 2,
        "description": "Fanta 1 L",
        "productName": "Fanta 1 Liter",
        "price": 1.99,
        "productId": 10
    }],
    "storeName": "My awesome shop",
    "status": 5,
    "timestamp": {
        "_seconds": 1590713204,
        "_nanoseconds": 916000000
    }
}  
'''  data 
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(data, cart_item), 
  JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.status') AS status, 
  JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.storeName') AS storeName,
  JSON_EXTRACT(cart_item, '$.qty') AS qty,
  JSON_EXTRACT(cart_item, '$.description') AS description,
  JSON_EXTRACT(cart_item, '$.productName') AS productName,
  JSON_EXTRACT(cart_item, '$.price') AS price,
  JSON_EXTRACT(cart_item, '$.productId') AS productId
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(data, '$.cart')) cart_item
```

result is

```
Row order_id    status  storeName           qty     description     productName         price   productId    
1   1           5       "My awesome shop"   1       "Sprite 1 L"    "Sprite 1 Liter"    1.99    9    
2   1           5       "My awesome shop"   2       "Fanta 1 L"     "Fanta 1 Liter"     1.99    10
```

Answer (score 0):

What you must do is to extract the values from the json data as:
SELECT .......
WHERE data->'$.storeName'= "My awesome shop" and data->'$.status' = 5

Extracting from the 'cart' or ´the 'timestamp' keys will give you a Json object that needs further extracting to get the data.
I hope it'll help you
You probably want to have a look at the MySql documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) or https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNNEST in the WHERE clause to access the cart's columns, and JSON_EXTRACT functions in the WHERE clause to filter the rows wanted. You need to take care on accessing either the json root or the array `cart`; `json_data` and `cart_items` in the example below (by the way, in your example `shopName` doesn't exist but `storeName` does).

```
WITH
  `myapp-1a602.firestore_orders.orders_raw_changelog` AS (
  SELECT
    '{"cart": [{"qty": 1,"description": "Sprite 1 L","productName": "Sprite 1 Liter","price": 1.99,"productId": 9}, {"qty": 11,"description": "Sprite 11 L","productName": "Sprite 11 Liter","price": 11.99,"productId": 19}],"storeName": "My awesome shop","status": 5,"timestamp": {"_seconds": 1590713204,"_nanoseconds": 916000000}}' json_data )
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, '$.status') AS status,
  JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, '$.storeName') AS storeName,
  JSON_EXTRACT(cart_items, '$.productName') AS product,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(cart_items, '$.qty') AS qty
FROM
  `myapp-1a602.firestore_orders.orders_raw_changelog`,
  UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json_data, '$.cart')) AS cart_items
WHERE
  JSON_EXTRACT(json_data,'$.storeName') like "\"My awesome shop\"" AND 
  CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_data,'$.status') AS NUMERIC) = 5
```

Comment: but in this way I can just extract the data from that only particular json and I want this to work in all the database with the select

Comment: The WITH clause is only for explanation purposes and it is aimed to demonstrate how the query can work based on the json document you shared (it is one row, according to your comments). You should change the FROM clause with the table that has the json documents and remove the WITH clause, I have updated my response to use the table firestore_orders.orders_raw_changelog instead, but the solution to your question are the extract functions explained also in other answers.